# I am trying to conduct a while loop but the loop is infinite and I am unsure why

Tags: javascript

I was constructing this code and after testing it, the code does not work and it froze the webpage, which I assume is because of an infinite loop. I am unsure what the problem is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Student Loan Payoff</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
function DisplayPayoffSchedule() {
    var amount, ir, mp, monthcounter;

    amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById('loanBox').value);
    ir = parseFloat(document.getElementById('rateBox').value);
    mp = parseFloat(document.getElementById('paymentBox').value);

    document.getElementById('scheduleDiv').innerHTML = 'Original loan amount: ' + amount + '<br>';

    monthcounter = 0;

    while (amount > mp) {
        amount = (1 + (ir / 12)) * amount - mp;
        monthcounter++;
        document.getElementById('scheduleDiv').innerHTML += ' Month ' + monthcounter + ': Amount Remaining : ' + amount + '<br>';
    }

}
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <p>
Amount of Loan: <input type="text" id="loanBox" size="6"><br>
Annual Interest Rate: <input type="text" id="rateBox" size="6"><br>
Monthly Payment: <input type="text" id="paymentBox" size="6">
    </p>
        <input type="button" value="Display Payoff Schedule"  onclick="DisplayPayoffSchedule();">
    <hr>
        <div id="scheduleDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error because of

```
amount = (1 + (ir / 12)) * amount - mp;
```

If you enter Monthly Payment is negative, the amount alway greater than mp and endless loop.

Should prevent input negative number.

Also should break while when monthcounter is too big.

```
if(monthcounter > 50){
    break;
}
```

Because if Amount of Loan is too big and Interest Rate and Monthly Payment is very small, it will repeat a lot of loops and seem as endless loop.

```
function DisplayPayoffSchedule() {
    var amount, ir, mp, monthcounter;

    amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById('loanBox').value);
    ir = parseFloat(document.getElementById('rateBox').value);
    mp = parseFloat(document.getElementById('paymentBox').value);

    if(mp < 0){
    alert('Monthly Payment must be positive');
    return;
    }

    document.getElementById('scheduleDiv').innerHTML = 'Original loan amount: ' + amount + '<br>';

    monthcounter = 0;

    while (amount > mp) {
        amount = (1 + (ir / 12)) * amount - mp;
        monthcounter++;
        document.getElementById('scheduleDiv').innerHTML += ' Month ' + monthcounter + ': Amount Remaining : ' + amount + '<br>';
        if(monthcounter > 50){
           break;
        }
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Student Loan Payoff</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
function DisplayPayoffSchedule() {
    var amount, ir, mp, monthcounter;

    amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById('loanBox').value);
    ir = parseFloat(document.getElementById('rateBox').value);
    mp = parseFloat(document.getElementById('paymentBox').value);
 
 if(mp < 0){
 alert('Monthly Payment must be positive');
 return;
 }

    document.getElementById('scheduleDiv').innerHTML = 'Original loan amount: ' + amount + '<br>';

    monthcounter = 0;

    while (amount > mp) {
        amount = (1 + (ir / 12)) * amount - mp;
        monthcounter++;
        document.getElementById('scheduleDiv').innerHTML += ' Month ' + monthcounter + ': Amount Remaining : ' + amount + '<br>';
        if(monthcounter > 50){
           break;
        }
    }

}
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <p>
Amount of Loan: <input type="text" id="loanBox" size="6"><br>
Annual Interest Rate: <input type="text" id="rateBox" size="6"><br>
Monthly Payment: <input type="text" id="paymentBox" size="6">
    </p>
        <input type="button" value="Display Payoff Schedule"  onclick="DisplayPayoffSchedule();" />
    <hr>
        <div id="scheduleDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, how do I change the statement to make it work? Do I change the condition to (amount <= mp)?

Comment: i updated answer, you add condition to check mp < 0 and return

Comment: I believe the page is still infinitely loading, do you know another alternative? Thank you for your help!

Comment: you should have if(monthcounter > 50){ break;  } to break the loop if monthcounter is too big